# Best Approach for Implementing Custom Post Types and Taxonomies for an Events Website?

Tags: custom-post-types

Hello fellow WordPress developers,

I'm working on creating a website for events and conferences using WordPress, and I'm trying to figure out the best approach for implementing custom post types and taxonomies to organize the content effectively. My goal is to have separate post types for different types of events (e.g., conferences, workshops, webinars) and relevant taxonomies like event categories, locations, and event dates.

I have a couple of questions regarding this:

Should I create separate custom post types for each event type (conferences, workshops, webinars), or is it better to have a single custom post type with different event categories?

How can I design the taxonomies in a way that provides a user-friendly filtering experience for visitors? Are hierarchical taxonomies like event locations and event dates suitable, or should I consider custom fields for specific attributes?

Are there any best practices or recommended plugins for managing custom post types and taxonomies? I want to ensure that the solution I implement is maintainable and doesn't lead to performance issues as the content grows.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, experiences, or recommendations you can share based on your expertise. If you've worked on similar event-focused websites or have encountered any pitfalls to avoid, please feel free to share your thoughts. Thank you in advance for your guidance!

Best regards,
Akshat

Comment: Can you edit the question to narrow this down to a single question? You can have multiple separate questions on the site, but bundling them all together severely reduces the chances of an answer. Remember this isn't a messageboard/forum so you need to be able to mark an answer as the _correct_ answer for the entire question, not just the best reply. Broad open ended discussions tend to get closed so be specific